# React Material - MUIDataTable - how to add content in column header

Tags: reactjs, mui-datatable

I use in my React app:

```
import MUIDataTable from "mui-datatables";
```

I'd like to add some button to my last column header (instead of the column name):

```
 <MUIDataTable
            data={data}
            columns={columns}
            options={options}
        >
        </MUIDataTable>
```

where columns:

```
export const columns = [
    {
        name: "name",
        label: "Nazwa",
        options: {
            filter: true,
            sort: true,
        }
    },
    {
        name: "productNumber",
        label: "Numer",
        options: {
            filter: true,
            sort: true,
        }
    }, (...)
```

How to do that? Is it possible? I can't find anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a custom body for column. You can add a column like this:

```
{
  name: "Age",
  options: {
     filter: false,
     customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => (
        <FormControlLabel
          control={<TextField value={value || ''} type='number' />}
          onChange={event => updateValue(event.target.value)}
        />
     )
  }
}
```

Comment: one more question - is it possible to add button only to the last column HEADER but the remaining rows in that column should contain data from data variable (like in other rows in other columns)

Comment: Ok I have solution for my problem - I have to use customHeadRender instead :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **customHeadRender**

```
const columns = [
    {
        name: "id",
        label: "Id",
        options: {
            filter: false,
        }
    },
    {
        name: "subject",
        label: "Subject",
        options: {
            filter: true,
            sort: false,
        }
    },
    {
        name: "button",
        options: {
            customHeadRender: ({index, ...column}) => {
                return (
                    <Button key={index}>
                        Click
                    </Button>
                )
            }
        }
    }
];
```